# Как принимать сообщения от сервера в разные переменные?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, сокет, клиент-сервер, chat

Есть чат на PyQt5. Сервер уведомляет всех подключенных клиентов о том, что кто-то подключился, и всех подключенных клиентов о том, что кто-то отключился.

На сервере есть список ников, под которыми заходят пользователи(при выходе они из списка удаляются).

Как сделать так, что если новый клиент подключился, ему бы отправляло список, но  он бы учитывался не как сообщение, а как ник, и заносился бы в listwidget?

Код сервера:

```
import time
import socket
import base64
import threading
from datetime import datetime

class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.all_client = []
        self.all_nicks = []
        self.now = datetime.now() 
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # Запускаем прослушивание соединений
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.server.listen(0)
        threading.Thread(target=self.connect_handler).start()
        print('Сервер готов к принятию подключений!')
        
    def connect_handler(self):
        while True:
            client, self.address = self.server.accept()
            user_nick = client.recv(7168)
            decoded_usernick = user_nick.decode('utf-8')
            if client not in self.all_client: 
                    if decoded_usernick not in self.all_nicks:   
                        self.all_client.append(client)
                        self.all_nicks.append(decoded_usernick)
                        print(decoded_usernick + ', ' + str(self.address) + 'Присоединился к серверу!')
                        threading.Thread(target=self.message_handler, args=(client, decoded_usernick, )).start()
                        for client in self.all_client:
                            client.send(f'Пользователь <{decoded_usernick}> присоединился к общению!'.encode('utf-8'))
                        
                    else:
                        client.send('Пользователь с таким ником уже есть в чате! \n'.encode('utf-8'))
            time.sleep(2)                
    def message_handler(self, client_socket, decoded_usernick):
        while True: 
            try:
                message = client_socket.recv(7168)
                if message == b'exit':
                    self.all_client.remove(client_socket)
                    self.all_nicks.remove(decoded_usernick)
                    for client in self.all_client:
                       client.send(f'Пользователь <{decoded_usernick}> отсоединился от чата!'.encode('utf-8'))
                    break
                for client in self.all_client:
                    if client != client_socket:
                            client.send(decoded_usernick.encode('utf-8') + ':'.encode('utf-8') + message)
            except:
                print("Сервер упал")
            
        
myserver = Server('0.0.0.0', 1234)
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from des import *
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QShortcut, QLabel, QApplication, QHBoxLayout
from datetime import datetime
class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.send_message)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.connect_server)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.ui.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.switchmode)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.ui.pushButton.setAutoDefault(True)  # click on <Enter>
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(self.ui.pushButton.click)
    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши по форме
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Если нажата левая кнопка мыши
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # Получаем координаты окна относительно экрана
            x_main = self.geometry().x()
            y_main = self.geometry().y()
            # Получаем координаты курсора относительно окна нашей программы
            cursor_x = QtGui.QCursor.pos().x()
            cursor_y = QtGui.QCursor.pos().y()
            # Проверяем условием позицию курсора на нужной области программы(у нас это фрейм) 
            # Если всё ок - перемещаем
            # Иначе игнорируем
            if x_main <= cursor_x <= x_main + self.geometry().width():
                if y_main <= cursor_y <= y_main + self.ui.frame_2.geometry().height():
                    self.old_pos = event.pos()
                else:
                    self.old_pos = None
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # Вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # Вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        try:    
            if not self.old_pos:
                return
            delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
            self.move(self.pos() + delta)
        except:
            pass    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            self.client.send(b'exit')
            self.client.close()
        except:
            pass        
    def smile1(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_1.text())
    def smile2(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_2.text())
    def smile3(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_3.text())
    def smile4(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_4.text())
    def smile5(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_5.text())
    def smile6(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_6.text())
    def smile7(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_7.text())
    def smile8(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_8.text())
    def smile9(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.insert(self.ui.smile_9.text())

    def connect_server(self):   
            
                try:
                    if self.ui.pushButton_5.text() == 'Подключиться!':
                        self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Отключиться!")
                        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
                        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/disconnect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                        self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)
                        
                        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        self.mainThread = chat(self.client)
                        self.mainThread.mysignal.connect(self.check_message)
                        self.ip = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text()
                        self.port = int(self.ui.lineEdit_3.text())
                        self.nick = self.ui.lineEdit_5.text()
                        self.client.connect((self.ip, self.port))
                        self.mainThread.start()
                        
                        self.client.send(self.nick.encode('utf-8'))
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                            
                        
                    elif self.ui.pushButton_5.text() == 'Отключиться!':
                        try:    
                            self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Подключиться!")
                            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
                            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                            self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)
                    
                            self.client.send(b'exit')
                            self.client.close()

                            self.ui.textEdit.clear()
                            msg = QMessageBox()
                            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
                            msg.setText(f"Успешное отключение от сервера {self.ip}:{self.port}")
                            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
                            x = msg.exec_()
                        except:
                            pass
                except:
                    self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Подключиться!")
                    msg = QMessageBox()
                    msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
                    msg.setText(f"Не удалось подключиться к серверу!")
                    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
                    x = msg.exec_()
                    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
                    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                    self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)  
    def switch_smile_theme_light(self):
        buttons = [self.ui.smile_1, self.ui.smile_2, self.ui.smile_3, self.ui.smile_4, self.ui.smile_5, self.ui.smile_6, self.ui.smile_7, self.ui.smile_8, self.ui.smile_9]
        for button in buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
    def switch_smile_theme_dark(self):
        buttons = [self.ui.smile_1, self.ui.smile_2, self.ui.smile_3, self.ui.smile_4, self.ui.smile_5, self.ui.smile_6, self.ui.smile_7, self.ui.smile_8, self.ui.smile_9]
        for button in buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
    def switch_smile_theme_neon(self):
        buttons = [self.ui.smile_1, self.ui.smile_2, self.ui.smile_3, self.ui.smile_4, self.ui.smile_5, self.ui.smile_6, self.ui.smile_7, self.ui.smile_8, self.ui.smile_9]
        for button in buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")     
    def switchmode(self):
        #светлый
        if self.ui.pushButton_7.text() == 'Светлый режим':
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setText('Неоновый режим')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/neon_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon)
            self.switch_smile_theme_light()
            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "background:#b8b8b8; border-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.frame_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #a3a3a3; border-radius: 7px"
            )
            self.ui.title1.setStyleSheet(
            "color: black;"
            )
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #c9c9c9;\nbackground-color: #DCDCDC;\ncolor: black;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #a3a3a3;\ncolor: black;\n}")
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
            self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #a8a8a8;\nbackground-color: #bdbdbd;\ncolor: black;")
        #Неоновый
        elif self.ui.pushButton_7.text() == 'Неоновый режим':
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setText('Темный режим')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/dark.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon)
            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.switch_smile_theme_neon()
            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 60, 147, 255), stop:1 rgba(126, 0, 172, 255)); \nborder-radius:7px;"
            )
            self.ui.frame_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); border-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.title1.setStyleSheet('color: #fff; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);')
            self.ui.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{\nbackground:rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:rgb(154, 0, 185);\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}'
            )
            self.ui.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{\nborder-radius: 8px;\ncolor: white;\nbackground-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground-color:rgb(199, 0, 0);\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;;\ncolor: white;\nbackground:rgb(199, 0, 0);\n}')
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 45, 110, 255), stop:1 rgba(104, 0, 142, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;\nbackground:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 79, 194, 255), stop:1 rgba(187, 0, 255, 255)); \nborder-radius: 7px;"
            )
        #темный
        elif self.ui.pushButton_7.text() == 'Темный режим':
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setText('Светлый режим')
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/light.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setIcon(icon)
            self.ui.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")

            self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "background:#1a1a1a; border-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.frame_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background:rgb(44, 44, 44); border-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.title1.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            )
            self.ui.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #404040;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:hover{\nborder: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}\n\nQPushButton:pressed{\nborder: 2px solid white;\nbackground-color: #444444;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;\n}")
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #666;\nbackground-color: #3b3b3b;\ncolor: white;\nborder-radius: 8px;"
            )
            self.switch_smile_theme_dark()
    
    def check_message(self, value):
        self.now = datetime.now() 
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M")
        
        
        if 'Пользователь' in value:
            
            self.ui.textEdit.append(f'[{self.current_time}] {value}')
            cursor = self.ui.textEdit.textCursor()
            textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat()
            textBlockFormat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
            
            cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat)
        else:
            self.nick1 = value.partition(':')[0]
            self.message1 = value.partition(':')[2]
            self.ui.textEdit.append(f'[{self.current_time}] {self.nick1}: {self.message1}')
            cursor = self.ui.textEdit.textCursor()
            textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat()
            textBlockFormat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
            cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat)
        if  self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText() == f'[{self.current_time}] Пользователь с таким ником уже есть в чате! \n':
            self.ui.textEdit.clear()
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setText("Подключиться!")
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/connect_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.pushButton_5.setIcon(icon)
            self.client.send(b'exit')
            self.client.close()
            
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка!")
            msg.setText(f"Пользователь с таким ником уже есть в чате!")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            x = msg.exec_()
        elif self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText() == f'[{self.current_time}] Пользователь <{self.nick}> присоединился к общению!':
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Успех!")
            msg.setText(f"Вы успешно присоединились к серверу {self.ip}: {self.port}!")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            x = msg.exec_()
                        
    def send_message(self):
        self.now = datetime.now() 
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M")
        if len(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()) > 0:
            message = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
            self.client.send(f'{message}'.encode('utf-8'))
            self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()

            self.ui.textEdit.append(f'[{self.current_time}] {self.nick}(Вы): {message}')
            cursor = self.ui.textEdit.textCursor()
            textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat()
            textBlockFormat.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
            cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat)

            
class chat(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    mysignal2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,server_socket, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.server_socket = server_socket
        self.message = None
        self.Nick = None
    
    def run(self):
            while True:
                try:
                    self.message = self.server_socket.recv(7168)
                    self.decoded_message = self.message.decode('utf-8')
                    
                        
                    self.mysignal.emit(f'{self.decoded_message}')
                except:
                    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = gui()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Рекомендую использовать в проектах на Qt кутешные же библиотеки, как то QThread, QTcpServer/QTcpSocket и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать так, что если новый клиент подключился, ему бы отправляло
> список, но он бы учитывался не как сообщение, а как ник?

Можно, например, типизировать сообщение. То есть, завести примерно следующий перечень типов сообщений (`MessageType`) и сам тип/класс сообщения (`Message`):

```
enum MessageType:
    HANDSHAKE = 1 # Отправляется/получается при подключении к серверу
    PLAIN         # Обычное сообщение
    ...           # Другие типы сообщений    

class Message:
     # Создаем сообщение
     # type - тип сообщения
     # payload - содержимое (для HANDSHAKE - никнейм и т.д., для PLAIN текст сообщения)
     def __init__(self, type, payload):
         self._type = type

     def type():
         return self._type
     
     # Формируем из сообщения QByteArray для передачи по сети
     def toByteArray(self):
         ...

     # Формирование объекта сообщения Message из QByteArray
     @staticmethod
     def fromByteArray(byteArray):
        ...
```

Далее, когда вы подключились к серверу, то отправляете ему

```
Message(MessageType.HANDSHAKE, <Данные клиента>)
```

На сервере вы проверяете тип входящего сообщения и если он `HANDSHAKE`, то отправляете клиенту текущий список подключенных клиентов, а каждому из текущих клиентов - данные нового клиента.

Если тип сообщения - `PLAIN`, то вы отправляете его каждому клиенту, которые в свою очередь получают его и выводят на экран и так далее.